# Add custom row when using select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

So I have a table with name, quantity and price

```
name        quantity        price        "custom-row"
a           12              5             12*5
b           20              3             20*3
c           18              10            18*10
```

Is it possible to add a "custom" row when using a select query? And I want the values in that row = quantity * price. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, quantity, price, (quantity * price) as custom_row
from table_name
```

you can just multiply your columns by column name and  after `AS` sign any column name you want

Comment: please write some text to your query

Comment: Why to use parentheses here?

Comment: @JonasMetzler sorry, but I'm used to it, because I have massive select's in queries in my job, it's easier for me to see. And less likely to make a mistake `(2+2)*2=8` 
`2+2*2=6`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select name, quantity, price, quantity * price as custom-row
from table_name
```

you can where if needed filtering

Comment: your script will not work because, a middle dash in the custom column name `-`

Comment: If this should be an issue, the query you've shown is also incorrect since the question was "custom-row", not "custom_row". We can use quantity * price as 'custom-row', but I think the author of the question is able to set a valid alias on his/her own.